# Get a transparent, nestable, wrappable background

Tags: color, line-breaking, highlighting, transparency

I like the way `soul` package enables coloring text background because it:

- adds no padding around `\hl{}`ed text (unlike `\colorbox` unless we set `\fboxsep=0cm` in a surrounding group)
- enables line wrapping (unlike `\colorbox` which is unbreakable)

However, it does not support:

- transparent background coloring
- nesting highlighted texts (which does makes sense if the background is transparent)

In other words, I am looking for a magical command which would allow me define a custom `\mhl` highlighting command so that:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\newcommand{\mhl}[1]{\whichCommandIsThat{black}{.2}{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{minipage}{3.4cm}
here is a \mhl{weird \mhl{nested, wrappable} weird} text
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

would produce:

[image]

Any idea?

Comment: Do you really need transparent background, i.e. seeing background pictures, or would it be enough that the colour in nested highlights becomes darker?

Comment: @samcarter Mmh.. I get the idea, but I guess I need true transparent. Not because of background pictures, but because darkenizing highlight color on each step down the tree would not be sufficient in the case of a `\mhl{black}{.5}{wide gray text both \mhl{red}{.2}{reddish} or \mhl{blue}{.2}{blueish sometimes}, see?}`.. :\

Comment: OK, this might still be doable without true transparency, by mixing the colours and darkening the result - unfortunately this is beyond my colour model knowledge.

Comment: @samcarter yeah, these are quite naughty calculations, uh? ;) Plus, with such a comfortable scripting language, it would be a nightmare XD

Comment: This should be doable with something like the `blend` mode in `tikz`, albeit that dealing with line breaks could be tough.

Comment: First you need to look at the xcolor and transparent (oberdiek) packages.

Comment: @JohnKormylo Interesting.. what would I look for in these ? :)

Comment: `xxcolor` does something similar but with textcolor. You can find the documentation in PGF's manual page 919.

Comment: @Symbol1 Interesting.. but this is for text color, not the background, right? õ.Ô

Comment: @iago-lito exactly! But at least the color part is done/doable. The real question is that macros form [tag:soul] cannot be nested.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Edit : see the updated full solution at the end.**

I do have a partial answer by using the `tcolorbox` package, where nesting and transparancy are possible:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{skins,breakable,xparse}
\newcommand{\mhl}[1]{%
   \tcbox[tcbox raise base, 
  left=0mm,right=0mm,top=0mm,bottom=0mm,boxsep=0.5pt,arc=0mm,
  boxrule=0pt,opacityfill=0.3,enhanced jigsaw,colback=gray!85!white,
   before=\relax,after=\relax]{#1}
}
\begin{document}
I say \mhl{Hello World} !
This box has a no \mhl{defined \mhl{height}} as you can see. 
The total \mhl{colored box is \mhl{shrunk to the 
\mhl{dimensions} of the \mhl{upper} part}. There} should be  no title. 
\end{document}
```

resulting in: 
[image]
Allas it is not breakable across lines. May be would it possible to emulate breakable capability by using `xstring` to handle text word by word...

**EDIT:**
A better solution uses the rather new `listofitems` package allowing to split the content of `\mhl` into words or inner `\mhl`, an to process them one by one. For this purpose the former macro `\mhl` calling `\tcbox` is recast into an internal macro `\mhl@int`. The line breaking works in the first level of \mhl, but not in the nested one.

New code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{trimspaces}
\usepackage{listofitems}
\tcbuselibrary{skins,breakable}
%
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\trim}[1]{\trim@spaces@noexp{#1}}
\newlength{\mhl@spacelen}
\settowidth{\mhl@spacelen}{\ }
\def\mhl@space{\kern\mhl@spacelen}
\def\mhl@backspace{\kern-1.1\mhl@spacelen}
%
\newcommand{\mhl@int}[1]{%
\mhl@backspace%
\tcbox[tcbox raise base,
left=0mm,right=0mm,top=0mm,bottom=0mm,boxsep=0pt,arc=0mm,boxrule=0pt,
opacityfill=0.3,enhanced jigsaw,colback=gray!85!white,
before=\relax,after=\relax]{\trim{#1}}
}
%
\newcommand{\mhl}[1]{%
\setsepchar{ }
\ignoreemptyitems
\readlist\phrase{#1}
\foreachitem\mot\in\phrase{\mhl@int{\strut\mot\mhl@space}}
}
%
\makeatother
%
\begin{document}
I say \mhl{Hello World}! This box has a no \mhl{defined \mhl{height}} 
as you can see. The total colored \mhl{box is shrunk to 
the\mhl{dimensions} of the upper part. \mhl{There} should be 
no lower part and no title.}
\end{document}
```

New result:
[image]

Further improvement would likely use recursive calls to `mhl` with a tracking of the level to get rid of some extra spaces and pushes the breakability into the nested highlighted sentences.

**Edit: full solution**

After a while, I finaly obtained a full solution of this question.
It still rely on `tcolorbox` for coloring the background and on parsing the text with `listofitems`. As nested `tcolorbox` are not breakable, the procedure loop on the sentence, highlighting it word by word, keeping a track of the level, and handling space as carefully as possible.

Here is the MWE (sorry for the French words, phrase=sentence, mot=word):

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{listofitems}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{skins,breakable,xparse}
%
\makeatletter
\newlength{\mhl@spacelen}
\settowidth{\mhl@spacelen}{\space}
\def\mhl@space{\hspace*{\mhl@spacelen}}
\def\mhl@sep{\hspace{\z@}}
\newcounter{nesthl}
\newif\ifmhlstart \mhlstartfalse
\newif\ifmhlend \mhlendfalse
%

\newcommand{\mhl@int}[2]{%
\ifcase#1\def\col{black!10!white}\or\def\col{black!10!white}\or\def\col{black!50!white}\or\def\col{black!85!white}\fi%
\tcbox[tcbox raise base, spartan, left=0mm,right=0mm,top=0mm,bottom=0mm,boxsep=0pt,arc=0mm,
boxrule=0pt,before=\relax,after=\relax, opacityfill=0.35,colback=\col
]{\strut #2}}

\newcommand{\mhl}[1]{%
\setcounter{nesthl}{1}%
\def\beforeskip{}%
\setsepchar{ }\ignoreemptyitems\readlist*\phrase{#1}%
\foreachitem\mot\in\phrase{%
    \IfBeginWith{\mot}{+}{\mhlstarttrue}{\mhlstartfalse}%
    \IfEndWith{\mot}{+}{\mhlendtrue}{\mhlendfalse}%
    \ifmhlstart \StrBehind{\mot}{+}[\nmot]\else\edef\nmot{\mot}\fi%
    \ifmhlend\StrBefore{\nmot}{+}[\nnmot]\else\edef\nnmot{\nmot}\fi%
    \ifmhlstart\addtocounter{nesthl}{1}\fi%
    \ifmhlend \ifnum\thenesthl>1 \def\beforeskip{\mhl@space}\fi
    \mhl@int{\thenesthl}{\nnmot}\mhl@sep\addtocounter{nesthl}{-1}%
    \else\mhl@int{\thenesthl}{\beforeskip\nnmot\mhl@space}\mhl@sep\def\beforeskip{}\fi%
    }
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\framebox{
\begin{minipage}{3.7cm}
here is a  \mhl{weird nested, +wrappable, +dummy blob+ and nice+} text
\end{minipage}
}
\end{document}
```

and the result:
[image]

The key idea in this solution consists in not using nested `\mhl` command that would  prevent wrapping, but to use a simple wiki-like markup inside the `\mhl` command, with `+` (it works also with `*`, and likely punctuation character if they are not active). Words starting with a `+` (without space) initialize a new level, and those finishing with a `+` close this level. The number of `+` must be even, and their relative position does matter.

The maximal nesting depth is not really limited, but to use a larger one than the 3 levels used here, one would have to modify the `\mhl@int` macro to enlarge the number of shades available (first line) and likely the `opacityfill` parameter of the boxes.

Comment: These are a few steps right on the way :) Thank you for your patience!

Comment: I finally propose a full solution, along the lines outlined at the end of my former post.

Comment: Nice.  No doubt this recent question, https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/443156/vary-transparency-of-colorbox-in-a-sentence, got you thinking about this one again.  I tried to upvote, but found I had already done so.

Comment: @Steven B. Segletes Sorry I was bot aware about this question and your nice solution, even if I don't really understand which was the problem. The great achievement in your answer is the ability to have line breaking, and furthermore keep the right justification. But for the present topic, the key problem was the nesting of successives levels.

Comment: That's a big work for a nice solution, thanks :D