# Visually highlight portions of a document

Tags: luatex, environments, highlighting

I'm looking for a possibility to visually highlight entire portions of a document. It could be a paragraph or entire pages. Ideally by changing the background color, but it could also be a colored bar along the margin.

It's important that the portion may contain anything: figures, tables, listings (!), etc. If there are floats contained, it's not important that they stay inside that environment, but they should also be highlighted somehow. So it should look something like this:

```
\begin{myhighlighter}{red}
foo
\url{test.com/a%20path.html}
\includegraphics{image}
\begin{lstlisting}
 !@#$%^&*(
\end{lstlisting}
bar
\end{myhighlighter}
```

Aesthetics are secondary. Is that possible?

Edit: I'm using LuaLaTeX

Comment: "Aesthetics are secondary"? Pay attention to what you say _here_ :)

Comment: Maybe have a look at OCG and its associated packages. It allows you to create layers inside PDF documents that can be hidden and shown. It could be a solution.

Comment: I think you should have a look at the [`tcolorbox`](http://mirror.koddos.net/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/tcolorbox/tcolorbox.pdf) package.

Comment: I think that the answers to these questions 
https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/360461
and 
https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/443156
could be a good stating point.

Comment: `tcolorbox` does not work with listings or URLs that contain a percent sign. Same with the `bcolorbox` solution from tex.stackexchange.com/questions/443156